# Characterization of flatness in terms of base change preservation

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, finitely-generated, flatness

Let $A \to B$ be a homomorphism of commutative rings and $M,N$ be two $A$-modules. Consider the natural homomorphism of $B$-modules

$\alpha_{M,N} : \mathrm{Hom}_A(M,N) \otimes_A B \to \mathrm{Hom}_B(M \otimes_A B,N \otimes_A B)$

defined by $\alpha_{M,N}(f \otimes b)(m \otimes b') := f(m) \otimes bb'$. Consider the two statements:

(1) $\alpha_{M,N}$ is an isomorphism for all $M,N$ whenever $M$ is finitely presented.

(2) $A \to B$ is flat.

Then it is easy to see that (2) $\implies$ (1). Namely, $\alpha_{-,N}$ is a natural transformation between finitely continuous functors and $\alpha_{A,N}$ is obviously an isomorphism, thus $\alpha_{M,N}$ is an isomorphism whenever $M$ is finitely presented.

**Question.** Does also (1) $\implies$ (2) hold? If this is false for trivial reasons, can we strenghten (1) a little bit so that it becomes true?

For example, one might try:

(1') For all $N$ the locus where $\alpha_{-,N}$ is an isomorphism is closed under finite colimits, or equivalently, under cokernels.

Then we still have (2) $\implies$ (1') and one might ask (1') $\implies$ (2).

Comment: Dear Martin: Are you assuming that $A$ is commutative?

Comment: Dear Martin: Did you look at Bourbaki, Algèbre, Section II.5.3?

Comment: 1) All rings are commutative here. Hence also the tag 'commutative algebra'. 2) I've looked at the section in Bourbaki. It says that $\alpha_{M,N}$ is an isomorphism when $B$ is a finitely generated projective $A$-module, even without assuming that $M$ is finitely presented. Well this assertions is trivial and is only related to my question, which basically asks for a converse. If $B$ is finitely generated projective over $A$, then in particular it is flat. So in this case (1) => (2) is OK.

Comment: Dear Martin: Thanks for your answer. I found it by chance. It's better to use the `@` sign to notify users.